# Tomcat use of static variables

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

Is it possible to use static variables in my project to store data for all Servlets (they are in one .war file) and different requests? (It's not data that belongs to a distinct session)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> data for all Servlets

You can use [`ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html)  for this.

> Defines a set of methods that a servlet uses to communicate with its servlet container, for example, to get the MIME type of a file, dispatch requests, or write to a log file.
>
> There is one context per "web application" per Java Virtual Machine. (A "web application" is a collection of servlets and content installed under a specific subset of the server's URL namespace such as /catalog and possibly installed via a .war file.)

For example:  in **web.xml**

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>param</param-name>
    <param-value>Myname is web xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

In your servlet

```
    public class ParameterServlet extends HttpServlet {

---

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
    ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    name= context.getInitParameter("param");
  }
```

[**A complete example here.**](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Servlets/Setthecontextparametersinwebxml.htm)

For Objects

setting

```
getServletContext().setAttribute("myObj", obj);
```

getting

```
MyObj attribute = (MyObj)getServletContext().getAttribute("myObj");
```

you can access those objects across `servlets`.

Comment: but i can't actually store objects there can I?

Comment: do those objects have to be serializable?

Comment: Nope. I don't read anything like that. No need to be `serializable`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.

However it is better to define these constants in your `web.xml` using the `<context-param> tag`.

Servlets can then retrieve constants defined using the `<context-param> tag` using the call:

```
 context.getInitParameter()
```

Example of name-value pairs in `web.xml`:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>name</param-name>
    <param-value>Joe</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>password</param-name>
    <param-value>password</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

in web.xml you can define

```
<context-param>
    <description>My variable</description>
    <param-name>variable.name</param-name>
    <param-value>value</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And then access it from Servlet code:

```
String variable = getServletContext().getInitParameter("variable.name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, the static variable will be accessible for all the servlet threads. But about using the static variable, you should make a proper decision depending on the factors like the life time of the data you want to store and the amount of data you are going to store.

And since it is used in servlets context, make sure that its thread-safe.

Comment: it is reead-only data that can be reloaded from a database at any time. So it should not be a problem would it?